# Selenium waiting until element equals something

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

C#, Winform, Selenium Firefox webdrivers.

Basically I need to wait till a certain element equals something in my program this is what i tried

```
public static string Watchprogress;


Watchprogress = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='watch-toolbar']/aside/div/span")).Text.ToString();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90)).Until(Watchprogress == "3");

 //And this

 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90)).Until(By.XPath("//*[@id='watch-toolbar']/aside/div/span")).Text.ToString() == "3");
```

got this error

The type arguments for method 'OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait.Until(System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. 5079

Still kinda new to selenium so i've been just doing trial and error.

Comment: What is `Watchprogress ` and don'w you need to set some kind of variable for the first line?

Comment: My apologize Watchprogress is a string that is public

Comment: And, if you print `Watchprogress ` does it return `3`?

Comment: yes when i do MessageBox.Show(Watchprogress); it shows the number 3 but it is a point type of things so sometimes it will be two then it will move up to 3 etc. that is why i need it to wait till it equals 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of things here. The implementation of `Until()` is wrong here. You either have to use `ExpectedConditions` here or write a custom functions(see bellow).See the [api](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/html/AllMembers_T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm)

```
By byXpath = By.XPath("//*[@id='watch-toolbar']/aside/div/span");
IWebElement element =
    new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(byXpath));


if (element.Text.Trim() == "3")
{
    //Pass this
}
```

Another options with LINQ

```
string watchprogress = new WebDriverWait(_driver, new TimeSpan(10)).Until(e => e.FindElement(byXpath)).Text.Trim();

if (watchprogress == "3")
{

}
```

Or

Simply if you want to wait until the `element` get's the text `3` use a `bool` indicator

```
bool watchprogress  =
                new WebDriverWait(_driver, new TimeSpan(10)).Until(e => e.FindElement(byXpath)).Text.Trim().Equals("3");
```

Or

```
 IWait<IWebDriver> wait = new OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.00));
 wait.Until(driver1 => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
 //First wait for the page to be completely loaded.
 WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90));
 wait2.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(StaleElementReferenceException));
 wait2.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='watch-toolbar']/aside/div/span")).Text.Contains("3"));
```

Comment: @Coderz It will wait `10s`(max) for the element's `Text` to be `3` an if it becomes `3` even before finishing `10s` it will return `true` since it is a `explicit` wait. If the `element`'s text never becomes `3` it will timeout after `10s` and return `false`

Comment: You can change any amount of time inside the TimeSpan here `new TimeSpan(10)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71417/discussion-between-saifur-and-coderz).